# How do you add a continuing education course?

Tags: resume

I did not take the course, I designed it and delivered it.  Any idea how to add this to a resume?

Comment: I have no prior experience with this so I will write as comment. I would list this experience as a job with beginning and ending dates as usual. In the job description state that you produced the material for the course and then delivered it. You can list related achievements (e.g. satisfaction rate, popularity of the course, quality of the material assessed by your superiors / whoever is relevant) as you would do for any other job.

Comment: It would help to know a bit more about the course. Was it for an academic institution, a MOOC university, or something else? How long did the course run? Did you deliver it multiple times, once or is it recorded and can be redelivered over and over without your involvement?

Answer (score 2):

Under either the experience or volunteer section depending on how you structure your resume. Generally this would be something to show if the position you apply can use skills in designing or delivering courses.